Issues with pytz.timezone in threading.Thread
I ran across an interesting bug yesterday with using pytz.timezone in a threading.Thread. When running the example code below, the Consumer.run() method appears to crash after the 1st iteration i.e., len(consumer.answers) equals 1.
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time
from numpy.random import randint
import pytz
import pendulum
import datetime

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue: Queue):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.queue = queue
        self.working = False

    def stop(self):
        self.working = False

class Producer(Worker):
    def run(self) -> None:
        print(f"{self}: Started producing")
        self.working = True
        while self.working:
            print(f"{self}: Put work")
            self.queue.put(randint(0, 256))
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def stop(self):
        self.working = False
        print(f"{self}: Stopped producing")


class Consumer(Worker):
    def __init__(
            self,
            queue: Queue,
            tz: str,
            ):
        super().__init__(queue)
        self.tz = tz
        self.answers = []
        
    def run(self):
        print(f"{self}: Started consuming")
        self.working = True
        i = 0
        while self.working:
            work = self.queue.get()
            print(f"{self}: Got work: {work}")
            # Let the queue know the task is done.
            self.answers.append(work + 1)
            print(f"{self}: Got solution: {work + 1}")
            print(f"{self}: Time: {datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone(self.tz))}")
            self.queue.task_done()

    def stop(self):
        # TODO: should this finish the queue?
        self.working = False
        print(f"{self}: Stopped consuming")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    queue = Queue()
    print(f"{queue}: Queue ready")

    print("Workers ready")
    producer = Producer(queue)
    consumer = Consumer(queue, tz="Europe/Brussels")
    print("Starting workers")
    producer.start()
    consumer.start()
    # Running for 10s.
    t1 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t1 <= 10:
        pass
    # Wrapping up.
    print("Stopping workers")
    producer.stop()
    consumer.stop()
    print(len(consumer.answers))
    print("Finished")

However, when simply swapping the calls to pytz.timezone for pendulum.timezone, everything appears to run as expected, i.e. len(consumer.answers) is approx. 19.
# Consumer
...

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self}: Started consuming")
        self.working = True
        i = 0
        while self.working:
            work = self.queue.get()
            print(f"{self}: Got work: {work}")
            # Let the queue know the task is done.
            self.answers.append(work + 1)
            print(f"{self}: Got solution: {work + 1}")
            print(f"{self}: Time: {datetime.datetime.now(tz=pendulum.timezone(self.tz))}")
            self.queue.task_done()

The question
Since I already have a working alternative, I am partly putting this out there for future reference. However, I am interested to know if anyone has any explanations for this behavior.

why are you using third party libraries in the first place? --> zoneinfo

Good point, I was not even aware of zoneinfo. This works fine as well. Thanks!

my assumption would be that for the standard library zoneinfo, multi-threading was considered during implementation. For pytz? Not sure. Anyway, pytz has been deprecated for a while now, so I wouldn't expect much to change in the future. If you can solve your issue with a standard lib tool, I would do so. Can't say anything on pendulum, never really used it.
